# Intercept and Change Request Location in Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

After looking around, I am unable to find an easy way to intercept requests made by the WebView and change the URL.

For example, I would like requests `*.melange` to actually route to `localhost:8080` while keeping the original URL as the `Host` header.

It appears, at first glance, that the easiest method to achieve this sort of URL rewriting would be to use the "new" (API Level 21 or higher) `shouldInterceptRequest`, copy the values out of the `WebResourceRequest` to make the HTTP request manually then return a `WebResourceResponse` with the correct values. In my mind, there "should" be an easier way to do this.

Please let me know if I am missing something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: "I would like requests *.melange to actually route to localhost:8080 while keeping the original URL as the Host header." - can you give one example url and the url which you would want to route it to?

Comment: Sure! And example url would be `http://app.melange/Index.html`, I would like that to route to `http://localhost:8080/Index.html` with the caveat being that the `Host` request header should remain as `app.melange`.

Comment: Of course, this is easy on iOS using the `canonicalRequestForRequest` method on a `NSURLRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class MyWebviewclient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if(url.contains("melange"){
                     String newUrl = "http://localhost:8080"+url.split("melange")[1];
                     loadUrl(newUrl);
                } 
                return false;
            }
}
```

Now,

```
yourWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebviewclient());
```

Comment: I apologize for being ignorant on the matter, but it was my understanding that `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` was only called for certain types of requests (e.g. not images), and additionally that `loadUrl` would, in fact, redirect the entire WebView to `newUrl` (while possibly preserving the original request). I apologize for not being thorough in my question, but I'm not sure if this solution is what I am looking for.

Comment: Did you try it once? I used it for a url that ended with .pdf, and it worked. And would want to know what does it mean by 'keeping original url as host header?'